# modifying group of rows using within function

Tags: r

I'm using `within` to modify my dataframe

```
df %>%
    within({
      NeedWork[Occupation == 'Driver'] <- sample(c(0,1), nrow(df[df$Occupation == 'Driver',]), replace=TRUE)
      NeedWork[Occupation == 'Engineer'] <- sample(c(0,1), nrow(df[df$Occupation == 'Engineer',]), replace=TRUE)
      NeedWork[Occupation == 'Doctor'] <- sample(c(0,1), nrow(df[df$Occupation == 'Doctor',]), replace=TRUE)
      NeedWork[Occupation == 'Lawyer'] <- sample(c(0,1), nrow(df[df$Occupation == 'Lawyer',]), replace=TRUE)
      .....
      NeedWork[Occupation == 'Accountant'] <- sample(c(0,1), nrow(df[df$Occupation == 'Accountant',]), replace=TRUE)
    })
```

I have a vector with over 150 unique Occupation values :

```
occupation <- c('Driver','Engineer',....'Accountant')
```

I'm new to R, I want to know if there is a way to loop over the vector into the within function so I don't have to write 150 lines of code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean something like:

```
for(i in 1:length(occupation)){
  df %>% within({ NeedWork[Occupation == occupation[i]] <- sample(c(0,1), nrow(df[df$Occupation == occupation[i],]), replace=TRUE) })
}
```

Does this work?